# merge 1st column and 2nd column; 3rd and 4th column and so on with a separator

Tags: text-processing, perl, r

I have a text file with 61000 columns and 173 rows. I would like to merge data on every 2 columns i.e., columns 1 and 2 should be merged, 3 and 4 should be merged, 5 and 6 should be merged and so on.

Sample input (tab separated):

```
Ind Pop scaffold1   X   scaffold1   X.1 scaffold3   X.2 scaffold4   X.3
a   antartica   1   1   1   1   2   2   1   1
b   antartica   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   2
c   antartica   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1
d   antartica   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   2
e   antartica   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   2
f   arctic  1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1
g   arctic  1   1   1   2   2   1   1   1
h   arctic  1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1
I   arctic  1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1
j   arctic  1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1
```

desired output (tab separated):

```
Ind-Pop scaffold1-X scaffold2-X.1   scaffold3-X.2   scaffold4-X.3
a-antartica 1-1 1-1 2-2 1-1
b-antartica 1-1 1-1 2-1 1-2
c-antartica 1-1 1-1 2-1 1-1
d-antartica 1-1 1-1 2-1 1-2
e-antartica 1-1 1-1 2-1 1-2
f-arctic    1-1 1-1 2-1 1-1
g-arctic    1-1 1-2 2-1 1-1
h-arctic    1-1 1-1 2-1 1-1
I-arctic    1-1 1-1 2-1 1-1
j-arctic    1-1 1-1 2-1 1-1
```

I tried to do it with R using the unite function of tidyr package. I was able to manage to merge two columns at a time using the following command:

```
     unite(df, newcol, c(scaffold1, X), remove=TRUE)
```

Not sure how to do it for multiple columns.

Any R or perl or linux command line approaches will be appreciated!

Comment: Yes, sorry about that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed -E 's/([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)/\1-\2/g'
```

### Explanation

- `sed -E 's/foo/bar/g'`: run `sed` with `-E` extended regex, replacing `foo` with `bar`, multiple times per line `/g`.
- `([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)`: match a non-tab character `[^\t]` that is one or more characters long `+`, and capture this in a group `([^\t]+)`. This is followed by a tab, then the non-tab characters again in another capturing group.
- `\1-\2`: replace this with the first capturing group, `-`, then the second capturing group. Essentially, replace the tab with  `-`.

### Why this works

`sed` is "greedy", i.e. tries to grab as many characters as it can. Hence the two capturing groups will try to be as long as possible. e.g. it will grab all of `a   antartica` (replacing it with `a-antartica`). The next time the search is run, it has already passed by `antartica`, and starts searching again on the tab after this word. Hence, the next match will be `1   1`, which it will replace with `1-1`. This pattern will will then repeat for each pair of columns. The greedy `+` is important. If you omit it, the pattern will just modify every tab.

Comment: Thanks! That works like a charm!!

Comment: No worries; glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

These are some of the methods you can use on your input "file.tsv":

```
$ perl -pe 's/\t/("-",$&)[$|--]/ge'  file.tsv
```

Here we are substituting every odd numbered tab with a dash.

```
$ sed -e '
    y/\t/\n/
    :a;s/\n/-/;s//\t/;ta
' file.tsv
```

This sed code will first change all tabs to newlines and then progressively change the odd ones to dashes and even to tabs.

```
$ perl -lpe 's/\t(.*?(?:\t|$))/-$1/g' file.tsv

$ perl -F'\t' -lane '
      push @A, join "-", splice @F,0,2 while @F;
      print join "\t", splice @A;
' file.tsv

$ perl -F'\t' -nae '($,,$")=("\t", "-");
   print map { "@F[2*$_,2*$_+1]" } 0..$#F/2;
' file.tsv
```